# how to change domain in aurelia to run application instead of localhost

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I want baseURl like 'project.com' instead of 'localhost:9000', because I am hitting some api which should be on same domain.

**My run.ts includes**

```
build,
done => {
browserSync({
  online: false,
  open: CLIOptions.hasFlag('open'),
  port: project.platform.port,
  proxy: "http://phenom-report.com:8001",
  logLevel: 'silent',
  server: {
    baseDir: [project.platform.baseDir],
    middleware: [historyApiFallback(), function(req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      next();
    }]
  }
}, function (err, bs) {
  if (err) return done(err);
  let urls = bs.options.get('urls').toJS();
  log(`Application Available At: ${urls.local}`);
  log(`BrowserSync Available At: ${urls.ui}`);
  done();
  });
  });
```

Comment: This probably requires your remote domain to have proper configuration to answer the request from your Aurelia application. Can you try explore that?

Comment: A link to a Discourse thread that may be relevant to your question is here https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/aurelia-cli-alameda-au-run-as-proxy/2255